# use of the definite article ' the'

Tags: articles, definite-article

When we talk about a noun in general it is not preceded by the definite article "the". As-

> Indian food is very delicious.

But in another sentence it is -

> The food of India is very delicious.

Why has here the definite article "the" been used before the noun "food", while here also the noun "food" has been used in general.

Should this sentence be -

> Food of India is very delicious.

Answer (score 1):

Food is a poor choice of noun to use for your example, it has two very different meanings:

When you say "The food of India" you refer to the specific current cuisine (the method of cooking) of India. You can use a definite article.

However when you say "Indian food" you're qualifying food as a noun meaning actual meals that people eat. So you can say "The Indian food is delicious." but it would mean at a meal where there was Indian food and Japanese food, that you were referring to the specific Indian food at that meal.

Without the article, "Indian food is delicious", you're not referring to any particular meal, and you are making a general statement about food (all the meals) which is(are) Indian.

Comment: *The X* refers to an instance of X.  Plain *X* refers to a type of X.